# Unable to Search or Sort through Webform Submitted Data

Tags: webforms, views

I created an exposed filter for my View that aggregates user-submitted webform data.  I was hoping this would allow them to search the View for specific webform entries.  Unfortunately, the View remains unsortable by column (although I checked the option to make every column sortable), and whenever I search via my exposed filter, it comes back with 0 results.

I've attached images of my Filter and View settings...  am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

View Settings:
[image: View Settings]

Filter Settings:
[image: Filter Settings]

Table Settings:
[image: Table Settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your FORMAT -> Format: Table | **Settings** for a checkbox that says `Override normal sorting if click sorting is used` and turn it on if it is not already.

Comment: Hi Darvanen,  Thanks so much for your advice.  I checked, and that checkbox is checked.  I'll edit my post to show my Table Settings, too.  Any further advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if the combined filter is interfering, maybe try removing that?

Comment: I thought that the exposed combined filter is what allowed the users to search?

Comment: Okay, interesting - I removed the filter, and yes, now the columns are sortable.  Now, how would I get search functionality, too...